# Why is my keyboard randomly repeating inputs?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, keyboard

When I press and hold some key it's repeated a random number of times. After that, the repeat stops, and I need to release the key and press it again to make repeat continue. If there's simultaneous sound playback *and* repeat is stopped, the sound's stuck while I hold the key with an unpleasant drumming as if there's some audio problem.

This issue is reproducible in Windows XP Safe Mode. On the same configuration under Linux there's no issue.

My configuration:

- PS/2 Logitech Keyboard
- USB Mouse
- MB M3A/H-HDMI
- Windows XP Pro English SP2 with added Russian layout (Windows XP loads via [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) 2)
- Realtek audio drivers for AC97

I tried to reinstall Windows XP, but this issue still reproduced, even after a clean install, only with Windows XP-installed drivers. Should I consider a BIOS update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed (let's pray J) by installing the latest version of the motherboard BIOS, which is described at the [Asus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus) site as "Fix the issue that PS/2 keyboard may be unable to continuously input after resuming from S3." By Jupiter, I don't know what S3 means :(

Comment: "S3" is the technically precise term for when your computer is in "standby" mode. Here's an overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_States

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a keyboard issue to me.

Honestly, the easiest and best way to test is to try another keyboard (preferably PS/2) on that machine. If it works, your keyboard is going bad. If not, then it may be something else (such as bad PS/2 or something else). You also may want to consider switching to a USB keyboard depending on your results of testing.